# google play store is not working mean it ceased at saying "Downloading"

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

please help i have a galaxy s4 value edition i9515.
google play store is not working mean it ceased at saying "Downloading" but nothing happened next, i have tried all the possible means. deleting updates/caches of framework play store and download manager which is also enable, restriction mode is not ticked, Reset the mobile makes a new google acount but no luck. thanks to all

Comment: PlayStore does the same thing to me when it is updating Google Play Store and Services in background. Make sure they are updated with recent version before you try anything.

Answer (score 0):

did a factory reset, same error when trying to download facebook "rpc:s-2:aec-2"
also adding account "sync apps with facebook" will not work:
logs me in
you have already authorized GALAXY S4
error "login failed. try later."
whole reason I did a reset, because I can no longer sync my facebook events to my android calendar
and now I cannot install or update facebook from  google play, I have to use amazon store